# Не можу знайти дослівний переклад "Waldeinsamkeit"

Tags: переклад, from-german

Нещодавно зіткнулась з таким словом, як Waldeinsamkeit, складно перекласти, і переклади різняться. Який буде найбільш коректним, і як вирішувати нюанси з такими термінами в статтях. Якщо брати речення то по сенсу виходить щось на зразок самотнього лісу, або відчуття самотності в лісі.
А переклад який знайшла в інтернеті ( Самотність, ліс, усамітнення)
В контексті речення в моєму випадку воно може мати значення самотності в лісі або самотнього лісу, мене цікавить як воно краще звучало би.

Comment: Запитання про переклад іноземних слів мають містити точне і повне пояснення іншомовного терміну своїми словами, контекст, у якому це слово треба перекладати, а також продемонструвати спробу самостійно відповісти на запитання і пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені у інтернеті/словниках відповіді не влаштовують автора запитання.

Comment: Пояснюю іншими словами коментар bytebuster: Ви можете питати про переклад іноземного слова, якщо точно знаєте, що конкретно воно у Вашому контексті означає (але при цьому з якихось причин не можете підібрати достойний український еквівалент) — в такому разі треба докладно і конкретно розписати, що саме воно означає (більшість тут не знає німецької). Якщо ж Ви самі не до кінця розумієте значення іноземного слова, то це [сюди](//german.stackexchange.com) або на інший форум, але не до нас.

Comment: Взагалі я так розумію, що «die Waldeinsamkeit» — це відчуття людини, що перебуває одна в лісі, причому мається на увазі не страх, а радше щось заспокійливо-медитаційно-утихомирююче. Складається з частин _der Wald_ «ліс» і _die Einsamkeit_ «самотність», тобто дослівно «лісова самотність». Але, хоча це назва відчуття, а не місця, але це слово часто вживається з прийменником «в», уособлюючи якесь чисто абстрактне місце заспокоєння (от як ми жартуємо «він в астралі» про того, що надто відволікся, але не жартома і про ін. стан). **Але трактування німецьких слів — поза компетенцією цього сайту.**

Comment: [«Untranslatable German Words: Waldeinsamkeit»](//blogs.transparent.com/german/untranslatable-german-words-waldeinsamkeit/) (англійською).